# Encoding image data from opengl into PIL Image

Tags: python, opengl

I have a list of characterers that I got from calling glreadPixels in openGL. I would like to convert this list of strings into an image and show it in python.
this is what I have tried :

```
st = ''.join((e)for e in get_frame_binary_data())
d = np.frombuffer(st.encode(),dtype=np.uint8,count=480*640*3).reshape([480,640,-1])   
plt.imshow(d)
plt.show()
```

The result I get from this is completely wrong. However if I write the same data into a text file( in opengl c++) and read it from python it works :

```
 with open('frame_binary_data', mode='rb') as f:
     d = np.frombuffer(f.read(),dtype=np.uint8,count=480*640*3).reshape([480,640,-1]) 
     plt.imshow(d)
     plt.show()
```

I guess it has something to do with encoding. Can anyone help me with that

Comment: Why do you encode the binary data as UTF-8??? And then call encode second time on `st`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Comment: Why are you calling `str(e)` (and the `st.encode()` is still there...)

Comment: Withou calling st.encode() np.frombuffer throws a " bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: That's because you use `''.join`; have you tried `b''.join`?

Comment: Just tried calling          st = b''.join(e for e in get_frame_binary_data()) and d = np.frombuffer(st,dtype=np.uint8,count=480*640*3).reshape([480,640,-1])    it throws the same error and

Answer (score 0):

Using glreadpixels you need to save the data as unsigned char, then in python code I convert the list into bytes using bytes(my_frame_data)

```
d = np.frombuffer(bytes(get_frame_binary_data()),dtype=np.uint8,count=480*640*3).reshape([480,640,-1])
```

that worked, The problem was that my data needed to be saved as unsigned char.